# What is the difference between msg.sender and address(this)?

Tags: ethereum, solidity, web3js

What is the difference between msg.sender and address(this) in the below code?

**pragma solidity ^0.8.0;

```
contract Escrow{
  address public payer;
  address payable public payee;
  address public lawyer;
  uint public amount;
  
  constructor(
    address _payer, 
    address payable _payee, 
    uint _amount) {
    payer = _payer;
    payee = _payee;
    lawyer = msg.sender; 
    amount = _amount;
  }

  function deposit() payable public {
    require(msg.sender == payer, 'Sender must be the payer');
    require(address(this).balance <= amount, 'Cant send more than escrow amount');
  }

  function release() public {
    require(address(this).balance == amount, 'cannot release funds before full amount is sent');
    require(msg.sender == lawyer, 'only lawyer can release funds');
    payee.transfer(amount);
  }
  
  function balanceOf() view public returns(uint) {
    return address(this).balance;
  }
}**
```

Comment: This could help regarding `address(this)` https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/40018/what-is-addressthis-in-solidity

Answer (score 9):

`msg.sender` is the address of the contract caller.

`address(this)` is the address of the smart contract itself.

Answer (score 7):

They are both addresses in Solidity, but there is a big difference between `msg.sender` and `address(this)`.

Allow me to use a simplified Smart Contract below to highlight the difference. All screenshots are from the Remix-Ethereum IDE (click [here](https://remix.ethereum.org/)).

```
pragma solidity ^0.8.0;

contract Escrow {
    
    address public owner;
    
    constructor() {
        owner = msg.sender;
    }
    
    function depositNothing() public view {
        require(msg.sender == owner, 'You are not the owner!');
    }
    
    function balanceOf() view public returns(uint) {
        return address(this).balance;
    }
}
```

**msg.sender**

We are talking about the ACCOUNT address from which the function in the Smart Contract was called. For example, suppose in the Remix Ethereum (IDE), the `Escrow` Smart Contract was deployed from the ACCOUNT address:

> 0x5B38Da6a701c568545dCfcB03FcB875f56beddC4

[image]

In that case, the State Variable `owner` will have the same address mentioned above. This is because the `constructor` function was called from that address.

[image]

Now, suppose we change the ACCOUNT address to:

> 0xAb8483F64d9C6d1EcF9b849Ae677dD3315835cb2

[image]

We then call the function `depositNothing` from the Smart Contract which was deployed earlier. You will get the following error, however:

[image]

This is because the `msg.sender` in the `depositNothing` function equates to the second ACCOUNT address. This obviously does not equate to the first ACCOUNT Address - `owner`. The second argument in the `require` function was therefore returned along with the error.

**address(this)**

This is not the same as the ACCOUNT Address discussed earlier. This strictly refers to the address given to the Smart Contract when it is deployed to the Ethereum blockchain.

This can be found here:

[image]

> 0xd8b934580fcE35a11B58C6D73aDeE468a2833fa8